# Rational solutions for $x^3+y^3=1$ where both x and y are non-negative

Tags: number-theory, rational-numbers, cubics, rational-functions

How can I find rational solutions for $x^3+y^3=1$ where both x and y are non-negative?

Edit: One of the answer in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1794760/90976) for general form of solutions

$$(a,b) \mapsto \left( \frac{a(a^3 + 2b^3)}{a^3 - b^3}, \; \; \frac{-b(2 a^3 + b^3)}{a^3 - b^3} \right).$$

It is obvious here that either $x$ or $y$ is negative.

Comment: You can’t. It’d contradict Fermat’s Last Theorem. Unless of course $x=0,y=1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you had $$\left(\frac ab\right)^3
+ 
\left(\frac cd\right)^3=1$$

then

$$(ad)^3 + (bc)^3=(bd)^3$$

which is a special case of $$p^3+q^3=r^3.$$

But it was proved by Euler no later than 1760 that this never happens, and possibly by Fermat as early as the 1630s.

The post you link to is about solutions of $x^3+y^3=9$, not of $x^3+y^3=1$.  Obviously $1^3+2^3=9$. The situation is different because $1$ is a rational cube and $9$ isn't.

Comment: Yes, later part gives general solution for $^3+^3=$ constant

Comment: No. It is a method for finding a family of solutions to $x^3+y^3=c$ **if** you already have one solution. Starting from $1^3+2^3=9$ we can find further solutions. But for $p^3+q^3=1$ there is nowhere to start.

Comment: Why is (0, 1) not a start?

Comment: Plug in $a=0, b=1$ in your formula and see for yourself.

Comment: Again, it doesn't contradict with being a start point, it just maps into itself because of no more solution.

Comment: MJD, I was thinking $p^3+q^3=r^3$ is a special case of $(a/b)^3+(c/d)^3=1$ because,
$p^3+q^3=r^3$
$(\frac{p}{r})^3+(\frac{q}{r})^3=1$
if we look at $(\frac{a}{b})^3+(\frac{c}{d})^3=1$, it will be subset of this where $b=d$. Am I missing something?

Comment: MJD actually it is not just special case of it, they are identical. Here is the proof.
we know $gcd(a,b) = 1$ and $gcd(c,d)=1$.
$(ad)^3 + (bc)^3=(bd)^3$ It is obvious that $b | ad$ and $d | bc$.
$b | ad$ and $gcd(a,b) = 1$  tells $b | d$, 
$d | bc$ and $gcd(c,d) = 1$  tells $d | b$.
Then it must be $b=d$ already.